# How to use localStorage in iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to access an website in `iframe` tag. That source in `iframe` uses localStorage. But i'm not able to access it since I am loading it in `iframe`. Here is my sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The iframe element</h1>
<script>")
localStorage.setItem("token", "some_token");
      localStorage.setItem("userId", "456");
      localStorage.setItem("userName", "demo");
      localStorage.setItem("userRole", "user_role");
</script>

<iframe src="https://some_third_party_url">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I access this url in Iframe using localStorage?

Comment: You can't unless you own the webpage inside the iframe. This happens to be a security measure to prevent anyone from accessing others website data.

Comment: So  localStorage works on the current html page but iframe is considered as new html page(Because iframe is loading whole some other host webpage). localStorage cannot pass those value to iframe. Or Iframe cannot access that localStorage. Right?

Comment: Yes. If the iframe has a website that also comes from your server, you have full access to that.

Comment: No the src which i'm accessing using Iframe is not from my server. i.e. totally different.server.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access the local Storage unless the third party URL and html file hosted are on the same domain. and for your use case you could use the window.postMessage to access the data across the windows or iframes.